# new directories are owned by non existent user 10001

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, permissions, user

I am currently trying to setup my raspberry pi as a webserver that serves files from a cifs share.

The problem I run into is that my while using ssh, my pi creates all new files/folder with a non existent user.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/www $ ls -lsa
total 4
0 drwxrwxrwx+  4 root pi      0 Sep  3 15:37 .
4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Sep  3 13:25 ..
0 drwxrwxrwx   3 1001 pi      0 Sep  3 15:28 .recycle
0 drwxr-xr-x  13 1001 pi      0 Sep  3 15:28 ttp-master
```

`pi@raspberrypi:/media/www $ mkdir non-sudo`

`pi@raspberrypi:/media/www $ sudo mkdir sudo`

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/www $ ls -lsa
total 4
0 drwxrwxrwx+  6 root pi      0 Sep  3 15:43 .
4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Sep  3 13:25 ..
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 1001 pi      0 Sep  3 15:43 non-sudo
0 drwxrwxrwx   3 1001 pi      0 Sep  3 15:28 .recycle
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 1001 pi      0 Sep  3 15:43 sudo
0 drwxr-xr-x  13 1001 pi      0 Sep  3 15:28 ttp-master
```

When I create files using the gui on my pi, it is also owned by the same user and group.

```
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 1001 pi      0 Sep  3 16:02 gui
```

I cannot access any files via the webserver configured to the /media/www directory, all it shows is error 403 forbidden.

When I create a new folder from my windows machine using the same share, the permissions appear as:

```
0 drwxrwxrwx   2 pi   pi      0 Sep  3 16:04 windows-gui
```